# Carriage return in tqdm.write()

Tags: python, progress-bar, carriage-return, tqdm

I am having issues with the usage of a carriage return with tqdm.write()

This code works perfectly, it make an animation of a spinning bar

```
step = 0
for x in range (0,50):
    animation = {0: '|',
                 1: '/',
                 2: '-',
                 3: '\\'
                 }[step]
    tqdm.write(animation, end='\r')
    step = (step+1) % 4
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

But if I create progress bar just before :

```
bar = tqdm(total=100)  # Here
step = 0
for x in range (0,50):
    animation = {0: '|',
                 1: '/',
                 2: '-',
                 3: '\\'
                 }[step]
    tqdm.write(animation, end='\r')
    step = (step+1) % 4
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I have just a display of the progress bar.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported as an issue in the official [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) github.

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/520

The author suggested a correction by using a prefix instead of end

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
from tqdm._utils import _term_move_up


prefix = _term_move_up() + '\r'
print('')
for x in trange(50):
    tqdm.write(prefix + "|/-\\"[x % 4])
    sleep(0.1)
```